# No parameterless constructor defined for this object. MVC 5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I have a problem when i try to code with .NET Framework(4.7.2) and EF Core(3.0) because usually i use .NET Core.
When i try to inject Repository(by its interface).

This is my code

SenderController.cs

```
public class SenderController : Controller
{
    private readonly ISenderRepository _sRepo;
    public SenderController(ISenderRepository sRepo)
    {
        _sRepo = sRepo;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

ISenderRepository.cs

```
 public interface ISenderRepository
{
    ICollection<Sender> GetSenders();
    Sender GetSender(int senderId);
    bool SenderExists(string name);
    bool SenderExists(int id);
    bool CreateSender(Sender sender);
    bool UpdateSender(Sender sender);
    bool DeleteSender(Sender sender);
    bool Save();
}
```

and this is what i get

[image]

i think i do wrong way for dependency injection in MVC 5. Can you help me to do that?
Thank you :)

Comment: "I have a problem when i try to code with .NET Framework(4.7.2) and EF Core(3.0)" - Pick one.

Comment: Can you post the SenderRepository class? The problem is likely in the implementation. Not in the interface.

Comment: Sorry, i just find the answer by using this in constructor :
private ISenderRepository _sRepo;
        public SenderController()
        {
            this._sRepo = new SenderRepository(new Data.ApplicationDbContext());
        }

Comment: Can you show your dependency injection configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have to inject your controller, you can use Autofac to help you

Answer (score -1):

I just fixing it by using this statement in constructor :

```
private ISenderRepository _sRepo;
    public SenderController()
    {
        this._sRepo = new SenderRepository(new Data.ApplicationDbContext());
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: This isn't a fix, it's just not using dependency injection. Too bad.

Comment: so how to really fix it?

Comment: As you wrote, your DI configuration is incorrect. Please add it to your question.

Comment: i'm still confused when i use DI in Core just add in AddScoped<> . where can i use it in .nET Framework?

Comment: In .NET Framework you have to use a third party DI library ([Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org/) is my favorite, but YMMV), and stich it to MVC using the `DependencyResolver.SetResolver()` API. Here's how Simple Injector does it: https://docs.simpleinjector.org/en/latest/mvcintegration.html